# how to covert string datatype to date datatype in HIVE?

Tags: sql, date, format, hive

I have a date in string format in hive table (like "20121021") How do I convert this into "yyyy-mm-dd" (ex: 2012-10-21 or 2012/10/21)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `cast()`:

```
select cast(substr(col, 10) as date)
```

At least, this works for the YYYY-MM-DD format.  I should also note that in a date context, a string such as YYYY-MM-DD will typically be converted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TO_DATE()](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html). Try following:

`TO_DATE('20121021')`

Or

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20121021', 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```